# pointer initialization does not produce stable result

Tags: c, pointers

I wrote a little program to understand better about pointers.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
  char buf[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
  int i;
  char ** ptr1;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    printf("------------------\n");
    printf("i = %i\n", i);
    printf("buf = %p\n", buf+i);
    ptr1 = (char **)&buf[i];
    printf("ptr1 = %p\n", ptr1);
    printf("*ptr1 = %p\n", *ptr1);
    *ptr1 = (char *)ptr1;
    printf("B ptr1 = %p\n", ptr1);
    printf("B *ptr1 = %p\n", *ptr1);
    printf("B **ptr1 = %i\n", **ptr1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The program outputs:

```
------------------
i = 0
buf = 0x7fff3d6898f0
ptr1 = 0x7fff3d6898f0
*ptr1 = 0x7fff03020100
B ptr1 = 0x7fff3d6898f0
B *ptr1 = 0x7fff3d6898f0
B **ptr1 = -16
------------------
i = 1
buf = 0x7fff3d6898f1
ptr1 = 0x7fff3d6898f1
*ptr1 = 0x7fff3d6898
B ptr1 = 0x7fff3d6898f1
B *ptr1 = 0x7fff3d6898f1
B **ptr1 = -15
------------------
i = 2
buf = 0x7fff3d6898f2
ptr1 = 0x7fff3d6898f2
*ptr1 = 0x9f00007fff3d6898
B ptr1 = 0x7fff3d6898f2
B *ptr1 = 0x7fff3d6898f2
B **ptr1 = -14
------------------
i = 3
buf = 0x7fff3d6898f3
ptr1 = 0x7fff3d6898f3
*ptr1 = 0x9b00007fff3d6898
B ptr1 = 0x7fff3d6898f3
B *ptr1 = 0x7fff3d6898f3
B **ptr1 = -13
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./test terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Here are my questions:

1. In the first loop iteration. After I did

   ```
   ptr1 = (char **)&buf[i];
   ```

   Then `ptr1` gets buf. Since I did not initialize `**ptr1` completely, I get a random address for `*ptr1`

   ```
   printf("*ptr1 = %p\n", *ptr1);
   ```

   However, I then initialize *ptr1 with the address of ptr1.

   ```
   *ptr1 = (char *)ptr1;
   ```

   So I expect `**ptr1 = 0`. But I get some random value every time I run the program. Why?
2. Why there is always a seg fault at the end of this program?

Comment: If you are casting pointers, 80% of the time it means you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem starts here:

```
ptr1 = (char **)&buf[i];
```

`char **` means "points to a region of memory containing a `char *`.  However you then point it at a region of memory that does not contain a `char *` variable. In fact that region contains `char`s.

This may have already caused undefined behaviour if `&buf[i]` is not correctly aligned for `char *`. However you definitely get undefined behaviour from the attempt to read through the pointer:

```
printf("*ptr1 = %p\n", *ptr1);
```

This line violates the strict-aliasing rule; a portion of a `char` array cannot be treated as if it contained a pointer .

So the behaviour of your program from this point onwards is undefined.

---

Let's imagine for a moment that the strict aliasing rule didn't exist (e.g. gcc has a mode for this, `-fno-strict-aliasing`). The effect of that line will be to read `sizeof(char *)` bytes from the location pointed to by `ptr1`, and treat them as being the representation of a pointer.

Your output indicates that this size is `8` bytes on your system. However your array is only `4` bytes in size. So you have read beyond the end of your array (causing undefined behaviour).

The following line `*ptr1 = (char *)ptr1;` writes beyond the end of the array, causing undefined behaviour again. This could already trigger the "stack smashing" detection, depending how accurate that detection is.

IMHO it doesn't make much sense to try and analyze what happens after writing past the end of the array.